# Current timestamp Nhibernate

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

I asked this question a couple days ago but I think I worded my question wrongly.
Is there a way to do :

```
 var item = session.get<Item>(id)
 item.accpt_date = current_timestamp //db current timestamp
 session.merge(item)
```

I cannot use on update/insert trigger because accpt_date is populated only when certain event occur.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
item.accpt_date = session.CreateSQLQuery("select current_timestamp")
                         .UniqueResult<DateTime>();
```

---

I have no idea what that `session.merge` is supposed to mean.